# restlet post method parameter is always null

Tags: rest, restlet

I have a simple form:

```
<form action="send_email" method="post">
<input type="text" id="message">
<button type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

It goes to the `handlePost` method in my resource. However `Representation entity` is always passed null.

```
@Post
public Representation handlePost(Representation entity) throws ResourceException{
    Form form = new Form(entity);  
    ...
    return StringRepresentation("test");
    }
```

Why is this? How can I get my form input value?

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer. Silly mistake. I had to put the `name` attribute in the element

```
<input type="text" id="message" name="message">
```